# FlutterFragmentActivity dont open app anymore

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I've install local_auth and change the MainActivity.kt like this.

before:

```
 import android.os.Bundle
    import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
    import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
    
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
  }
}
```

after:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.app.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
  }
}
```

my gradle.properties is

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

and when a make the change of the MainActivity.kt the app don't open anymore. can anyone help with this?

Comment: Hi Gustavo, it would be good to post what behavior/error you're seeing and any basic steps you already took (like flutter doctor, flutter clean).

Comment: the most interesting is that dont show any error, simply close, when i run flutter clean sometimes give the error: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received.. but flutter doctor is all ok here